# Customizing a Javascript Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to customize a javascript alert? I was wanting to make an alert for my contact form validation. Is this possible or am i just dreaming...If so, i would love some help making one or a jsfiddle example!

Comment: i have tried some modals, but they are too complicated...i am only 15, so i am new to this stuff. :)

Comment: Age is not a hindrance. I know a person here that is 14 and is much more superior/geeky than the older guys.

Comment: Age has nothing to do with anything. Don't be silly and never use it as an excuse or reason.

Comment: Sorry, do you have an example you can show me...

Comment: @EliteGamer never let age get in the way or be an excuse. It's great that you are only 15 and are learning this stuff early! Good luck to you...

Comment: @Elite Gamer First, I concur that an age of 15 is not an impediment. It may even be an advantage, certainly so over my age, 72, when the mind simply isn't what it used to be. Now to your problem. I did enough exploration of modal popups to satisfy my personal stylistic desires, and the one I settled on is jQuery Impromptu available at trentrichardson.com as I remember. For my likes you can make it look good even for messages larger than you would normally use an alert for, as in the initial screen of http://terryliittschwager.com/WB/JWB.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alert boxes are browser specific and cannot be modified.

Your best bet is to use something like jQuery UI dialog.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Here's a pretty simple example...

http://jsfiddle.net/jcreamer898/c4RNq/

Comment: No problem man, I posted an example fiddle for ya as well. Let me know if you need any other help! Feel free to hit me up anytime... http://about.me/jcreamer898

Comment: yes he can change alert dialog, everything is replaceable in prototype based languages

Comment: are you sure, look at my answer and try it

Comment: What you are doing is replacing the built in `alert` with your own. *technically* that works, but I don't believe that's what he was looking for, and it's generally bad juju to replace built in browser functionality...

Comment: technically javascript is modeled as prototype language and you shouldn't be afraid to change or adopt features ;) I don't want to argue with you. Basically every undocumented unexpected implementations is bad implementation :) so you could be right here :)

Answer (score 2):

you can rewrite alert() function and put in it any jQuery popup plugin, like jQuery UI Dialog

```
window.alert = function(message){
               $( "#dialog-message" ).html("<p>"+ message + "</p>");
               $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

}
```